# Group by multiple fields in stream java 8

Tags: java, lambda, group-by, collectors

I have a class:

```
    public class PublicationDTO {

     final String publicationName;
     final String publicationID;
     final String locale;
     final Integer views;
     final Integer shares;
}
```

A need to get sum of views and shares. For test i created a list:

```
        PublicationDTO publicationDTO1 = new PublicationDTO("Name1", "name1", "CA", 5, 6);
        PublicationDTO publicationDTO2 = new PublicationDTO("Name2", "name2", "US", 6, 3);
        PublicationDTO publicationDTO3 = new PublicationDTO("Name1", "name1", "CA", 10, 1);
        PublicationDTO publicationDTO4 = new PublicationDTO("Name2", "name2", "CA", 2, 3);

        List<PublicationDTO> publicationDTOS = List.of(publicationDTO1, publicationDTO2, publicationDTO3, publicationDTO4);
```

I want to group objects in list by publicationName, publicationId and locale and get result list like:

```
List.of(new PublicationDTO("Name1", "name1", "CA", 15, 7),
        new PublicationDTO("Name2", "name2", "CA", 2, 3),
        new PublicationDTO("Name2", "name2", "US", 6, 3));
```

I found a solution like:

```
List<PublicationDTO> collect = publicationDTOS.stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(PublicationDTO::getPublicationID))
            .values().stream()
            .map(dtos -> dtos.stream()
                    .reduce((f1, f2) -> new PublicationDTO(f1.publicationName, f1.publicationID, f1.locale, f1.views + f2.views, f1.shares + f2.shares)))
            .map(Optional::get)
            .collect(toList());
```

but the result not grouped by locale and I'm not sure if it works by publicationId. Please let me know how to properly use collectors in such case?

Answer (score 1):

You are only grouping by `getPublicationID`:

```
.collect(groupingBy(PublicationDTO::getPublicationID))
```

Since those fields you are interested in for grouping are all strings you could concatenate them and use that as a grouping classifier:

```
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.getPublicationName() + p.getPublicationID() + p.getLocale()))
```

Comment: but how to sum more than one field? I mean views and shares?